# ListView doesn't fire ItemInserting after adding an attribute to a TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have a ListView to enter new contacts into our database, which works fine until I add custom attributes to a textbox in the InsertItemTemplate to provide some JavaScript functionality.

Here is a snippet of the ListView:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lvContacts" runat="server" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            ...
        </ItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <div class="borderedBox">
                <h3>
                    ADD OTHER CONTACT</h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="leftFields">
                        <asp:Label ID="astContactType" runat="server" CssClass="fieldLabel">Contact Type *</asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactType" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightFields">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="ADD NEW" Style="width: 150px; margin-top: 27px; margin-left: 0px;" CommandName="Insert" />
                    </div>
                    <br style="clear: both;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
        </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

This works fine as it is and btnAdd hits the ItemInserting function which is declared as follows:

```
Protected Sub lvContacts_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewInsertEventArgs) Handles lvContacts.ItemInserting
    ...
End Sub
```

In the ItemCreated function I've added code to "Initialise" the TextBox by adding an attribute with a JavaScript function which effectively adds dummy text into the Control which disppears when the user clicks on it. However if I leave this code present the ItemInserting function is no longer reached. Here is the ItemCreated function:

```
Protected Sub lvContacts_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lvContacts.ItemCreated
    Dim txtContactType As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("txtContactType")

    ControlHelper.InitialiseTextbox(txtContactType, "Contact Type")
End Sub

(This next part is in a separate file in the App_Code folder)
Public Class ControlHelper
    Public Shared Sub InitialiseTextbox(ByVal Text As TextBox, ByVal DefaultValue As String)
        Text.Text = DefaultValue
        Text.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "textFocus('" & Text.ClientID & "', '" & DefaultValue & "')")
        Text.Attributes.Add("onblur", "textBlur('" & Text.ClientID & "', '" & DefaultValue & "')")
    End Sub
End Class
```

This method of initialising TextBoxes works correctly by adding the attributes to the TextBox, which also functions correctly. Any ideas why the ItemInserting no longer works when I do this though?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/328680/problem-accessing-controls-clientid-on-asp-net-listviews-itemcreated)? It looks like accessing ClientID from the ItemCreated event can cause some issues, maybe it's preventing the other event from firing or being correctly handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ali Shahrokhi pushed this in the right direction and deservedly received the bounty. To solve the problem we removed the `InitialiseTextbox` function from the `ItemCreated` section and instead added the following:

```
Protected Sub lvContacts_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvContacts.PreRender
    Dim txtContactType As TextBox

    For Each item As ListViewItem In lvContacts.Items
        txtContactType = item.FindControl("txtContactType")
        ControlHelper.InitialiseTextbox(txtContactType, "Contact Type")
    Next

    txtContactType = lvContacts.InsertItem.FindControl("txtContactType")
    ControlHelper.InitialiseTextbox(txtContactType, "Contact Type")
End Sub
```

This loops through each of the items in the ListView and Initialises them, and then it Initialises the textbox of the `InsertItem`.

Answer (score 1):

On your ListView control add two more event attributes same as below:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvContacts" runat="server" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" 
          OnItemInserting="lvContacts_ItemInserting"
          OnItemEditing="lvContacts_ItemEditing" 
          OnPreRender="lvContacts_PreRender" >
```

And change your code like this:

Set an integer variable in your class scope first then on ItemEditing event set the index value to your variable and use pre_render event to set your attributes on your controls:

```
Private itemIndex As Integer = -1

Protected Sub lvContacts_ItemEditing(sender As Object, e As ListViewEditEventArgs)
     itemIndex = e.NewEditIndex
End Sub

Protected Sub lvContacts_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim txtContactType As TextBox
    If itemIndex <> -1 Then
        txtContactType = DirectCast(ListView1.Items(itemIndex).FindControl("txtContactType"), TextBox)
        ControlHelper.InitialiseTextbox(txtContactType, "Contact Type")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This was almost correct. Certainly `PreRender` was the place to go, however it was `InsertItem` that we needed to get the item for, not the current `EditItem`. (`EditItem` isn't used in this `ListView`). I have awarded the bounty for pushing us in the right direction. We added the following: `txtContactType = lvContacts.InsertItem.FindControl("txtContactType")` and then called the `ControlHelper.InitialiseTextbox` method.